# Is this movie tactic realistic?

Tags: tactics

In the movie "[Children of Glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Glory)", there's the tank scene, *(I wouldn't ask about the validity of war films in normal cases, but this isn't from Hollywood)* which plays out in the following way:

- Someone shouts that the tank is coming, at this point, the barricade is ready.
- Everyone retreats into the nearby houses.
- The tank comes, along with the supporting infantry.
- The rebels open fire from the windows and quickly grind the support down.
- Then the tank is lured into a trap, where it's flooded with Molotov cocktails, thrown from the windows.
- The crew escapes through the belly hatch.
- A street kid rushes in front of the tank and attempts to take the crew out with a (possibly stolen) pistol.
- The kid gets himself killed immediately.
- The rebels attack from two sides and successfully take out the crew from their covers.

Here's the clip:https://youtu.be/hBgqXO70t6k?t=129

**Is this a realistic tactic, or it would have gotten the rebels killed in real life?**

*It's said, that they've put a significant amount of research into the movie, I'm interested in whether it's true or not.*

Comment: Wasn't this standard tactics against Soviet tanks in Afghanistan?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Idk

Comment: This might be a better fit for Movies and TV SE.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why not,

<s>- Someone shouts that the tank is coming, at this point, the barricade is ready.</s>

- Everyone retreats into the nearby houses.
- The tank comes, along with the supporting infantry.
- The rebels open fire from the windows and quickly grind the support down.
- Then the tank is lured into a trap, where it's flooded with Molotov cocktails, thrown from the windows.

This is the only section which is debatable and really depends on the model of tank, but it is possible as proved by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJnXZBc6g_I) 
Basically how it would work is as follows:
[image: Where to aim on the tank]
You drop the cocktail on the engine grill at the back, the burning gas and oil would suffocated the engine and could set fire to some petroleum parts/residue inside the engine, along with damaging cables and other external instruments. If there is lack of oxygen inside the tank the crew may need to escape through the belly batch in which case you could then shoot at them.

- The crew escapes through the belly hatch. A street kid rushes in
  front of the tank and attempts to take the crew out with a (possibly
  stolen) pistol.

  - The kid gets himself killed immediately.
  - The rebels attack from two sides and successfully take out the crew from their covers

Comment: Having watched that scene, the mistake is they drop the cocktails on the *front* of the tank. The crew is then shown firing from under the tank, presumably using the T-34-85's *tiny* belly hatch. The front of the tank would lack large ingress points for the fuel, nor has much inside to burn. In the final shot, it's somehow burning from stem to stern. If it were a green crew they may have panicked and bailed out upon the first hint of smoke, but it doesn't explain why the tank is burning in the rear from a fire on the front hull. An experienced crew would have stayed in the tank and reversed.